# How does EclipseLink detect first access to make lazy fetching?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

Could anyone explain how EclipseLink detects the first access to field to make lazy fetching? It seems there is some `magic` and I can't find a way how it is done.

If I understand it right for `@OneToMany` relation EclipseLink creates intance  of `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList` which controls the access. But I can't understand what EclipseLink does for `@ManyToOne` relation.

Comment: That `magic` is called `proxy`. You actually get a proxy object not the actual entity; The benefit of returning a proxy is that we can enhancement the object with functionality like initialize a parent `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`. You can read more about [How does a JPA Proxy work](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ManyToOne or OneToOne case EclipseLink does code enhancement to detect the access. 
That means instead of the real object you have a proxy in place.

There are docs:

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/mappingintro002.htm#CHDJAHDC

Also interesting to read is the chapter about weaving. https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/app_dev005.htm#CCHJEDFH